# AngularJS not returning JSON data from service

Tags: json, angularjs, service

I would like this custom service(I know its not the best code) to return this JSON data but nothing is returning no matter what I try. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am sure it is something simple that I missed. Here is [my code](http://jsbin.com/pujeh/1/edit)

Comment: Doesn't the factory have to be defined before the Controller?

Comment: AD.Net's answer is correct. You only had those two errors. You ought to look up Dependency Injection, to better understand why you shouldn't reference `carData` in your HTML.  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in the HTML (just AwesomeCars, not AwesomeCars.carData)

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="car in AwesomeCars">
```

and you need to inject 'carData' in the controller

```
chadTerm.controller('chad-midterm-controller', ['$scope', 'carData', 
  function($scope, carData) {
        $scope.AwesomeCars = carData.cars;
}]);
```

[updated code](http://jsbin.com/nahoromu/2/edit?html,js,output)